# PL SQL Function throws error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

This is my function

```
declare

b_date date;
reset_status integer:=0  ;

begin

select lst_reset_dt_tm
into b_date

from TABLE1
where schm_sts in ('READY','NOT READY')
and schm_nm like 'SC%'
  and upper(srvr_nm) = ( select upper(machine)
                  from v$session
                  where program like '%(PMON)%');
select 1
into reset_status
from TABLE1
        where schm_nm = upper('OC1')
        and lst_reset_dt_tm > to_date(b_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  and upper(srvr_nm) = ( select upper(machine)
                  from v$session
                  where program like '%(PMON)%');

 dbms_output.put_line(reset_status);
exception
when no_data_found then
 dbms_output.put_line(reset_status);
end;
/
spool off
```

when i compile i get the error 
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 16

Basically the lower part of the query is failing ,this however works on an oracle 11g machine but not on oracle 12c. Can anyone help me debug ?

Comment: That is the data type of column `b_date`?

Comment: no its a variable which will store the value lst_reset_dt_tm which will be used later for comparison

Comment: The block is not called a function, it is an anonymous block.

Comment: You declared the variable `b_date` to be of `date` data type. So, then, what is this doing in your code? `... to_date(b_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')` If you want to truncate the date to the beginning of the day, use `trunc(b_date)`, not some form of `to_date()`.

Comment: Which line, exactly, is "line 16" in your code? From what you posted (formatted, including the blank lines) it would be `where program like '%(PMON)%');` but I doubt that this line would throw the error you reported. It is more likely the `to_date()` applied to a date; the error may be caused by your `nls_date_format` setting, which may be different from session to session (explaining why this doesn't fail on another machine; if Oracle wasn't Big Brother trying to fix our mistakes, that should fail on EVERY machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaushik is absolutely right, this is an anonymous block, not a function. That said this error occurs when you compare a numeric field to a character field. My suspicion is that  svr_nm or machine is a numeric field, I can't tell which. Making both character will solve your issue.

Or the issue is your second SQL statement, I am converting everything using to_char, you just need to do the fields that are numeric. Try running this SQL and see if it works, if it does, strip out all TO_CHAR's for character fields.

```
DECLARE
    b_date         DATE;
    reset_status   INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT lst_reset_dt_tm
      INTO b_date
      FROM table1
     WHERE schm_sts IN ('READY', 'NOT READY')
       AND schm_nm LIKE 'SC%'
       AND UPPER (TO_CHAR (srvr_nm)) = TO_CHAR (
                                           (SELECT UPPER (machine)
                                              FROM v$session
                                             WHERE program LIKE '%(PMON)%')
                                       );

    SELECT 1
      INTO reset_status
      FROM table1
     WHERE TO_CHAR (schm_nm) = UPPER ('OC1')
       AND lst_reset_dt_tm > TO_DATE (b_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
       AND TO_CHAR (UPPER (srvr_nm)) = TO_CHAR (
                                           (SELECT UPPER (machine)
                                              FROM v$session
                                             WHERE program LIKE '%(PMON)%')
                                       );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (reset_status);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (reset_status);
END;
/
```